What is the reactive power of a capacitive circuit?
I want to understand the reactive power in a purely capacitive load.  Surprisingly, I couldn't find the formula for this anywhere, so I derived it myself, and would like to ask 1. Is this formula correct and 2. Is there a reference for it?
Consider a pure sine wave of frequency \$f\$, amplitude \$A\$ in a circuit with capacitance \$C\$ and negligible resistance.  There will be negligible resistive power, but reactive power will be $$P = 4AfC.$$
Derivation: $$
\omega = 2\pi f \
\text{Avg Power} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}Pdt \
= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}VC\frac{dV}{dt}dt \
= \frac{C}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}A\sin \omega x \ dx \
= \frac 2 \pi A \omega C \
= 4 AfC.
$$
Is that correct?

Correction
Corrected based on feedback from Hearth
$$
P = 2A^2fC.
$$
Derivation:
$$
\omega = 2\pi f \
\text{Avg Power} = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2}Pdt \
= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2}VC\frac{dV}{dt}dt \
= \frac{2C}{\pi} \int_0^{t=\pi/2}A\sin \omega t  dV \
= \frac{2C}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2}A \omega \sin \omega t  \cos \omega t
dt \
= 2A^2fC.
$$

Check the dimensions--you're claiming that [power] = [voltage][capacitance][frequency], which works out to [power] = [current], which is plainly false.

@Hearth Thanks! Is the fixed formula correct?

The maximum current magnitude occurs at the zero-cross for the voltage. So the product is zero there. The minimum current magnitude of zero occurs at the voltage peaks. So the product is zero there, as well. For a period of time between any adjacent pair of these two conditions, which occupies a quarter-cycle, the product is either entirely positive or entirely negative.
If you choose to integrate and form an average for just one such quarter-cycle, then you will get a non-zero result. But if you integrate over any even number of such consecutive quarter-cycles, then you will get a zero result.
But let's go with a single quarter-cycle:
$$\begin{align*}
\overline{P}&=\frac1{t_1}\int_{t=0}^{t_1}V_{_\text{C}(t)}\,I_{_\text{C}(t)}\:\text{d}t, &\text{where } t_1&=\frac1{4f}
\\\\
&=4f\int_{t=0}^{t_1}\left[V_0\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)\right]\cdot\left[\omega\,C\,V_0\cos \left(\omega\,t\right)\right]\:\text{d}t, &\text{where } \omega&=2\pi\,f
\\\\
&=4f\,\omega\,V_0^2\,C\int_{t=0}^{t_1}\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)\,\cos \left(\omega\,t\right)\:\text{d}t
\\\\
&=4\,f\,V_0^2\,C\int_{\phi=0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin\left(\phi\right)\,\cos \left(\phi\right)\:\text{d}\phi, &\text{where } \phi&=\omega\,t
\\\\
&=2\,f\,V_0^2\,C\int_{\phi=0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin\left(2\phi\right)\:\text{d}\phi
\\\\
&=2\,f\,V_0^2\,C\left[-\frac12\cos\left(2\phi\right)\right]_{\phi=0}^{\frac{\pi}2}
\\\\
&=2\,f\,V_0^2\,C
\end{align*}$$
Let's assume a quarter-cycle using \$C=10\:\mu\text{F}\$, \$f=1\:\text{kHz}\$ and \$V_0=1\:\text{V}\$. The above would predict \$20\:\text{mW}\$. Let's see what LTspice shows:

That matches.
Let's set \$V_0=2\:\text{V}\$. The above would predict \$4\times\$ larger, or \$80\:\text{mW}\$. LTspice shows:

That matches, as well.
I think your corrected formula is now okay.
